# Does dependency injection belong in constructors, setters or other methods?

Tags: design, dependency-injection

I can write code like:

```
var dependency = "Hello!"
var something = new Something(dependency);
something.DoStuffWithDependency();
```

Or I could write it like:

```
var dependency = "Hello!"
var something = new Something();
something.DoStuff(dependency);
```

Where the first example takes the dependency in the constructor and uses it in some method.

Because it's a dependency, does it belong in the constructor? Or should it be injected into the method?

Comment: Whatever is required to build an instance with a valid state. Is the dependency mandatory for the object to function? Then it should be in the constructor.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable with the example given.  Both approaches are valid depending on the larger design needs.  In a lot of cases, there won't be a clear advantage to either approach.  If you pass the dependency in prefer [immutablity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but. Is it not a debate of DI vs Strategy Pattern?

Comment: Those aren't even the only two options. Using a Dependency Injection framework is another choice, for example using Autowire

Answer (score 6):

Both examples are bad. You don't instantiate a class to call a single method on it and then abandon the instance.

In other words: it depends. The question should be answered *conceptually* based on your *actual scenario*, not technically based on an abstract scenario.

If your Something has a bunch of methods and several of them act on the same dependency and a single instance will have several of these methods called, then the dependency is better as a field.

If your Something has several methods, and multiple dependencies each of which is used only by a single method, then it's better to pass it into the method.

But you also need to consider whether these dependencies are actually easily *available* at the point the object is constructed, or at the point the method is called. That could also influence the design.

Comment: What's relevant here is not how many methods are dependant on this value, but rather whether different invocations of those methods should always act on the same instance of the dependant value, or if they instance of the dependency is specific to that one invocation of the method.  The dependency may only be used by one method, but still make sense as a field if each invocation of the method needs to use the same object instance, and multiple methods all dependant on that type may not want a field if it makes sense for each invocation to use a different instance.

Comment: Both examples are bad because one method is being invoked? That's unfair. Surely you don't think that's his entire program.

Comment: @user889742: It's actually not that uncommon to see objects created just to call one method on them, and it's a code smell. As given, the artificial example code has that smell. If OP would have given example code closer to what his program actually does, the answer could have been more specific.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt By the way, there's a difference between being a code smell and being bad. While its a code smell and warrants a second look, creating an object for 1 function call is sometimes valid. See for example how Math.random was superseded by new Random().nextDouble();

Comment: @user889742: not a great example - in almost all cases you'd want to reuse that Random object, not create a new one for every call.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should put the dependency in the constructor if you want to use it for more purposes than the .DoStuff method. In that way, the dependancy is reusable.

If it is strictly for the .DoStuff method, I would only inject it into the method once.

This is how it's been taught in general to me as a student

Answer (score 2):

In this example, it doesn't much matter.  There is nothing wrong with a stateless instance, so the empty constructor is fine.  There is nothing wrong with holding state to be used by the method.

There are consequences though.  It's hard to see them here because construction and use have been mixed together.

Say you want to call `doStuff()` from a place that doesn't have any knowledge of your dependency.  It only knows about `Something`. You now have to make this place aware of the dependency to call your method.

Now if this new place is already aware of the dependency, and indeed if it has a few different ones to call, and there's no need to remember it then passing it in through a method that is hanging off a stateless instance is fine.

Some hate the idea of a stateless instance so they would rather make `doStuff()` static.  This works but is limiting since now you can't pass that stateless instance around.  Anything that calls a static `doStuff()` is calling a concrete implementation directly.

The non static stateless instance avoids that, letting you pass whatever version of `Something.doStuff()` you like.  You can treat your method as a function.  Indeed this line of thinking can lead us to single method interfaces and lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

Is the dependency part of the class, or the method invocation?

If the dependency is part of the class's identity, or data it needs to carry around, then pass it into the constructor.

If the dependency is only used in the method and nowhere else, pass it into the method.

In other words: in the context of the class declaration, do you use that dependency anywhere outside of the method's scope other than variable declaration and initialization?

Comment: This is a good point, having them in the constructor (thus being an instance variable) may decrease the level of cohesion in method of that class, which is not desirable.  http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics#LCOM

Answer (score 1):

I guess you set the dependency to delegate some function or as alternative to inheritance to add or alter the functionality of a class without extending it.

**One:**

In most similar cases you inject the dependency in order for it to be used in more than one place so it makes sense to have it as part of the state, i.e, several public or private methods could delegate some function to the dependency you injected. You can inject the dependency either in the constructor or with getters.

**What's more, you can inject more that one dependency** to delegate several functions to them:

```java
Thing t = new Thing(method, collation, locale);
t.convert(someData);
t.validate(someData);
t.format(someData);
```

or

```java
Thing t = new Thing();
t.setMethod(method);
t.setCollation(collation);
t.setLocale(locale);
t.convert(someData);
t.validate(someData);
t.format(someData);
```

**Two:**

**If you only pass an object to a method to be used in that method and that is, it's not really considered injecting a dependency.** It's passing a parameter to a method that just happens to be a non-primitive type, even if you call some of that object's methods. Once `doStuff(Dependency d)` is done running, no reference to `d` is held inside the class' state, so nothing was "injected" into the class.

It's like this:

```java
public method PrintPersonDetails(Person p){
      p.printDetails();
      // when it ends, no reference to p stays inside this class
      // so you injected nothing
}
```

---

**So, to answer your question**, the dependencies you want to form be of the objects' state and **to which the object will delegate some functions, thus changing its behavior without having to extend the class**, can be passed *either in the contructor or via getters*.

The other thing is not dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

My rule is : "You should expect the method to return the same result if you call it with the same parameters"

So. if the dependency has state which changes the result of the method, make it a parameter of the method. If the dependency just configures the behaviour of the class then pass it in the constructor.

But. I favour the constructor. So if for example I have a IWeatherService, obviously the weather can change, so two calls to a Method : WeatherIn(city) may return different results.

Rather than the ugly WeatherIn(city, weatherService) I would go for WeatherIn(city, datetime) to achieve the statelessness and keep the construction parameter